# Framework 7: How do you re-use a picker for dynamically created input forms?

Tags: html-framework-7

I have a picker that sets the duration of a workout. The user can click on a button that generates new input forms(for new workouts). What I'd like to do is change the picker input parameter to attach itself to the new input forms when the user click on them. This is to avoid creating a new picker each time a new workout is generated.

Is this possible? If yes, how can you do this?

I tried to something like:

```
picker.input = *insert new input here*;
```

but it returns an error in the framework7 code:

```
framework7.js:9914 Uncaught TypeError: p.input.parents is not a function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can generate it via Dynamic Picker Modal (http://framework7.io/docs/picker-modal.html#dynamic-picker-modal) and place it into your form.

With `myApp.pickerModal(pickerHTML, removeOnClose)` you can customize `pickerHTML` in order to satisfy your needs.